# Issues with reactivePoll Not Triggering valueFunc on Status Change in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that interfaces with an external API through a Python script. The app needs to handle asynchronous operations where it waits for a "run" (initiated by the user) to complete. I'm using reactivePoll to periodically check the run status and update the UI accordingly. My setup involves checking the run status returned by a Python script (my_python_script$get_run_status) and updating the UI when the status changes to "completed".
Here is the reactivePoll code:

```
runStatusPoll <- reactivePoll(5000, session,
  checkFunc = function() {
    if (!is.null(runID()) && waitingForRun() == TRUE) {
      tryCatch({
        status <- my_python_script$get_run_status(run_id = runID(), thread_id = thread_ID())
        print(paste0("This is the run status: ", status))
        return(status)
      }, error = function(e) {
        print(paste("Error fetching run status:", e$message))
        return("error")
      })
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  },
  valueFunc = function() {
    status <- runStatusPoll()
    if (status == "completed") {
      threads <- my_python_script$get_messages(thread_id = thread_ID())
      if (length(threads) > 0 && !is.null(threads[[1]]$content[[1]]$text$value)) {
        assistant_reply <- threads[[1]]$content[[1]]$text$value
        append_message("Assistant", assistant_reply)
        session$sendCustomMessage('typeWriter', list(text = assistant_reply))
      }
      waitingForRun(FALSE)
    } else if (status == "error") {
      waitingForRun(FALSE)
    }
  }
)
```

The console output:
"This is the run status: in_progress"
"This is the run status: in_progress"
"This is the run status: completed"
"This is the run status: completed"
"This is the run status: completed"
"This is the run status: completed"
I am not sure why the valueFunc isn't being triggered when the status changes to completed? I've been at this for days any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `valueFunc` is not called ? Try to put a tracing print of status at the beginning of the function. If it prints something then the problem is somewhere in the remaining part of the function where you retrieve the result. Also in `checkFunc` you are getting the status with get_run_status on python while you are using runStatusPoll in `valueFunc`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want a `reactivePoll` since you wait for an initialization by the user. Moreover `valueFunc` returns nothing.

That said, your `valueFunc` calls `runStatusPoll` and that makes no sense. You should move the body of `checkFunc` to `valueFunc`, something like this:

```r
runStatusPoll <- reactivePoll(
  5000, session,
  
  checkFunc = function() {
    !is.null(runID()) && waitingForRun() == TRUE
  },
  
  valueFunc = function() {
    if (!is.null(runID()) && waitingForRun() == TRUE) {
      status <- tryCatch({
        status <- my_python_script$get_run_status(run_id = runID(), thread_id = thread_ID())
        print(paste0("This is the run status: ", status))
        return(status)
      }, error = function(e) {
        print(paste("Error fetching run status:", e$message))
        return("error")
      })
      if (status == "completed") {
        threads <- my_python_script$get_messages(thread_id = thread_ID())
        if (length(threads) > 0 && !is.null(threads[[1]]$content[[1]]$text$value)) {
          assistant_reply <- threads[[1]]$content[[1]]$text$value
          append_message("Assistant", assistant_reply)
          session$sendCustomMessage('typeWriter', list(text = assistant_reply))
        }
        waitingForRun(FALSE)
      } else if (status == "error") {
        waitingForRun(FALSE)
      }
    }
  }
)
```